# Is convergence of expectations preserved by multiplication (under some special conditions)?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $\{A_n\}_n$ and $\{B_n\}_n$ be two sequences of real-valued random variables.
Assume

1. $A_n$ is nonnegative and $A_n \to A$ in distribution, with $E[A_n]=E[A]<\infty \  \forall n $.
2. $B_n$ is uniformly bounded, $B_n \to B$ in distribution, and $E[B_n]\to E[B]$.
3. $A_n B_n \to AB$ in distribution.

So both sequences converge in distribution and there is convergence of the means (not in mean).
Can we conclude that $E[A_n B_n] \to E[AB]$ ?
Information on uniform integrability of $A_n$ is not available.

Comment: Is $B_n$ bounded for each $n$, or is the sequence $(B_n)$ uniformly bounded?

Comment: It is uniformly bounded: $|B_n|< c \ \forall n$

Comment: What is the context of this problem?  Where does it come from?  What are your thoughts about it?

Comment: I'm trying to prove weak convergence for a sequence of r.v.'s and I ended up wondering whether the above statement is correct. I formulated the question in general terms so it can be useful to others as well.
- If $A_nB_n\to AB$ in prob., then we have convergence of expectations iff the sequence is uniformly integrable.
- I tried to use Skorohod representation with Fatou's lemma, but I would need $A_n$ to be bounded by an integrable random variable for that to work.
So I'm starting to think one might need  $A_n$ to be uniformly integrable otherwise the statement might be false.

Answer (score 1):

Using Skorohod representation and Theorem 4.6.3 in [https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) yields $\{A_n\}_n$ is uniformly integrable. This implies $\{A_n B_n \}_n$ is uniformly integrable and thus, again by Skorohod representation and Theorem 4.6.3, $E[A_n B_n] \to E[AB]$.